# How do I find the character encoding of a ms access database?

Tags: ms-access, encoding

How do I find out the **character encoding** for the tables in my MS Access 2003 database.

For example:

- Windows-1252
- ISO 8859-1
- US-ASCII

Comment: Is Access the programming environment or are you not using Access at all, but instead Jet/ACE as data store only? My answer takes you at your word based on your tags, and assumes you're needing the answer within Access.

Comment: I am using ADODB to get the data out of access. If ADODB can tell me what character encoding it is using fantastic. This information should also be available within Access no?

Answer (score 1):

Is there something not working with CurrentDB.CollatingOrder? I don't know where you look up the value of the resulting number, but in my American DBs, it returns 1033, which is quite familiar as the American English character set.

Ah, yes, if I go into the Object Browser in the VBE and search for CollatingOrder, one of the results shows an ENUM called CollatingOrderEnum, and by clicking on each in turn, you can see its value.

DBEngine(0)(0).CollatingOrder is the same property, and can be used with DAO from outside Access. There is, perhaps, a way to get it with ADO/OLEDB, but I don't use either of them so can't point you in the right direction there.

Comment: You might want to see if you can ask this question on Michael Kaplan's blog, http://blogs.msdn.com/b/michkap/ . I can't find anything in Access itself that seems to expose this, and have no Jet references that postdate Unicodification of Access.

Answer (score 1):

Beginning with Access_2000 (which was based on Jet 4.0), Access databases store text data internally as Unicode. So if your database file really is an Access_2003 database then the DAO, ODBC, and OLEDB access methods should all return Unicode strings.